# Why is my hyperlink alignment different?

Tags: html, css

If you look here http://jsfiddle.net/Grek/JRqcB/ you'll see that the hyperlink seems to be bottom-aligned compared to the text. What is the issue and how can I fix it? Many thanks

Comment: Really? Your CSS only has two rules, one of them refers to your `a` tags and has a rule called `vertical-align`. Maybe that has something to do with the vertical position of your `a` tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `vertical-align:middle` in #activity-container a

Answer (score 3):

Remove the CSS property `vertical-align:middle` in the following style:

```
#activity-container a {
    color: #467FD9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JRqcB/3/

Answer (score 3):

Remove `vertical-align: middle;` from css for the link.

See also: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html